# Changing user edit form

Tags: 8, forms

I am trying to change my Drupal 8 theme user edit form but can't find a template to override. I want't to make something like this: http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/page_user_profile_1_account.html

Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preface, changing the Drupal user edit forms is not the most straightforward thing to do (when compared to changing the templates for regular site's theme), but it is *possible*, just as anything else.  Firstly, are you currently using one of the stock admin themes (e.g. Seven)?  If so, you will need to sub-theme that, which is done in the same way as you create a normal theme, then you just configure your site to use that admin theme.  Then, you can override templates.  In the case of the user edit form, it will depend the level of customization you want to do to the form. If you turn on debugging (see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates), then you will be able to see the templates you need to override at the form and field level.  Of course, if you can do what you need to do with CSS or Javascript (and it's not too kludgey), that is something to consider as well to avoid the pain of having to mess with the generation of the actual markup.

Comment: Hi morpheus, thank's for your answer, that clears up my mind a bit. 
My theme uses Classy core theme and I have Twig debug enabled, with that I was able to change almost everything I needed except for the edit forms. So, you're saying that I need to create another theme based on Seven for example and then override the right template? Or I just need to change the base theme from my custom theme? Thank you.

Comment: I tried what you said and the only template suggested is form.html.twig wich has only two variables: children and attributes, where children is rendered html with everyithing I need to change. Is there a way to parse that html to object so I may be able to change what I need? Thanks

Comment: I manage to achieve what I needed by hooking the user form and changing weights and adding classes before my elements. Anyway, you helped. Thank you.